# Download a zip file using xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I Am Newbie in Xamarin. Our Xamarin forms app supports Android and IOS. Most of the app functionality is written in PCL class library which is referred in the above platforms. 
Now we need to download a zip file using this app. Some posts are suggesting to handle it in common PCL library and some are suggesting to handle it in respective native projects. I am bit confused, which is the better approach of the two. Are there any limitations in this approaches? 
If possible could you please share a sample app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code to download the file in PCL. For downloading file you can make use of HTTPClient. At the same time you have to call dependency service and write the dependent code in corresponding android/ios projects to specify the file output path.
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/network/web_requests/download_a_file/ uses webClient which is written in android. You can use HTTPClient to get same result in PCL